# Where does Git store remote tracking branches

Tags: git

I have to Git repos `repo1` and `repo2`. There are three branches `master`, `alpha` and `beta` in `repo1`. `repo2` clones from `repo1`.

In `repo2`, I can see remote tracking branches with `git branch -a`:

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/alpha
remotes/origin/beta
```

But the folder `.git/refs/remotes/origin/` in `repo2` only has a single file `HEAD`, whose content is:

```
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

So this `HEAD` is a symbolic ref. But why does it point to a ref that doesn't exist? BTW, where does `repo2` store the information of `alpha` and `beta`? (`repo2` knows `alpha` and `beta` because it displays them in `git branch -a`.)

Comment: Which version are you running? and did you `init` and `fetch`, or just `clone`. I ask because there are settings available for what should be fetched by default.

Comment: Is this all on the same machine, and could your installation be using symlinks rather than having a true second copy?

Comment: @PhilipOakley They're on the same machine. And the answer is pointed out below. I forgot the packed-refs issue...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The refs are probably "packed" in `.git/packed-refs`.

Comment: `git help pack-refs` clarifies everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The information is in `.git/config` and is updated by tools like `git remote` when you add or modify remotes.  There is a manual page on [`git-config`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).  If you search for "tracking branches" you'll see details of how they are configured.

Comment: This is false. Remote tracking branches are not stored in `.git/config`. All branches are stored in `.git/refs/` or `.git/packed-refs`. Only tracking metadata for local branches and fetch and push refspecs are stored in `.git/config`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: The word "tracking" in the question seemed to be the most specific part of the request, so I focused on the tracking metadata.

Comment: This fixed my issue: visual studio 2013 current branch does not have an upstream branch configured